# Trouble with Google's new "No Captcha reCaptcha" & form page & php & javascript

Tags: javascript, php, forms

Let me start with a HUGE Thank You in advance.  I've been trying to get this right for way too long!

On my wife's website I have a contact.html page for website visitors to be able to email her, and a contact.php which handles the background stuff for it.  I am a novice at form pages and the supporting php pages and feel pretty lucky that I got it working right a year or so ago when I did it.  Since then I've tried several times to get a captcha set up right but have not been successful.  Now with Google's new No Captcha reCaptcha, I've been trying again.

I have taken several example php pages with No Captcha reCaptcha code in place that people put online to use, and tried getting it to work with my form page after making changes to the code to work with my site, but can't get it to work right.  I think it has something to do with the fact that all of the example pages that I've found online use METHOD=POST in their form code, and my form page doesn't.  On top of that, I don't know the difference between METHOD=POST and what my form code does, and don't know javascript even though it's in the code on my page.

Also below in the code, you'll see that there is a confirmation page that the website visitor is taken to after clicking submit on the contact.html webpage.  If someone could tell me how to require text in the fields before the message gets sent, that would be great too.

Below is the actual form code from my contact.html page, and below that is the entire code from my contact.php page.  If someone could help me get this working right I would be very thankful!

Form Code (complete with my No Captcha reCaptcha public key):

```
<form id="ContactForm" action="emale/contact.php">
                        <div class="wrapper">
                            <div class="column1">
                                <label>Tell Us Your Name:<br /><input 
type="text" name="name" value="" class="input"  /></label><br />
                                <label>Tell Us Your E-mail Address:<br />
<input type="text" name="email" value="" class="input"  /></label><br />
                                <label>Tell Us Your County of 
Residence:<br /><input type="text" name="county" value="" class="input"  /></label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="column2">
                                Tell Us Your Message:<br /><textarea 
name="message" cols="" rows="" ></textarea>

                            <br /><br />

                            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-
sitekey="6Lf3Me0SAAAAAPjA2cfG1Rkzn30joCcuPJbVYhhw"></div>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="alignright">

                <div align="right"><a href="#" class="link" 
onclick="document.getElementById('ContactForm').reset()"><span><span>clear</span></span></a>
                              <a href="#" class="link" 
onclick="document.getElementById('ContactForm').submit()"><span><span>submit</span></span></a>
```

And now below is the entire code from my contact.php page.  This how it is with no Captcha code present.

```
<?
$subject= "My Wife's Website Inquiry From ".$_GET['name'];
$headers= "From: ".$_GET['mail']."\n";
 $headers.='Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';
mail("mywife@mywifeswebsite.com", $subject,  "
<html>
<head>
 <title>Contact letter</title>
</head>
<body>

<br>
".$_GET['name']."
<br />
".$_GET['email']."
<br />
".$_GET['county']."
<br /><br />
".$_GET['message']."
</body>
</html>" , $headers);
header("Location: http://www.mywifeswebsite.com/complete.html");
?>

<script>
    resizeTo(300, 300)
    //window.close()
</script>
```

Thanks again.  Please let me know if there are any questions or something that I need to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you've provided, your problems are that:

- You haven't included the required JavaScript to make the CAPTCHA work.
- You don't have anything in your PHP file to validate the CAPTCHA results.

Follow the directions on Google's website to implement this correctly.

Comment: Yes, I was showing the contact.php page purposly without the captcha code in it.  I tried several variations of the php code from several blogs etc on the web where people were trying to help.  Each one of those (after I changed some code to work with my form) either let the person submit the form data whether the captcha checkbox was checked or not, or after clicking submit, was taken to a completely white webpage with no text or anything and left hanging.

Comment: I was saying in my original post that I was thinking that I must be approaching it wrong because the php code that I was trying all mentioned METHOD=POST and my form doesn't use that.  So I was showing my original php code without any captcha code...hoping that someone could show me the right way to do it.  Google's instructions on this (particularly for novice users) is really terrible.  Not much instruction at all.